# Plotly go: how to add an image to the hover feature?

Tags: python, plotly, hover

The first segment of code below (code # 1) generates a graph for which 1) when you hover over each point, the data associated with each point is displayed and 2) when you click on each point, the data associated with each point is saved to a list. For this code, I would also like to display the image associated with each point. Assume the dataframe df has a column 'image' which contains the image pixel/array data of each point. I found code online (code #2) that implements this image hover feature but without the click feature. I'm having a hard time combining the image hover feature with the click feature. So, basically, I'm trying to combine the click feature (click on point, it's data is saved to a list) of code # 2 into code # 1.

CODE # 1 (with click feature):

```
import json
from textwrap import dedent as d
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import dash
from dash import dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

# app info
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}

# data
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

# plotly figure
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country", title="No label selected")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='figure1',
        figure=fig,
    ),

    html.Div(className
             ='row', children=[
        html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown(d("""Hoverdata using figure references""")),
            html.Pre(id='hoverdata2', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns'),
                 
                     html.Div([
            dcc.Markdown(d("""
              
              Full hoverdata
            """)),
            html.Pre(id='hoverdata1', style=styles['pre']),
        ], className='three columns')   
    ]),
    
])

# container for clicked points in callbacks
store = []

@app.callback(
    Output('figure1', 'figure'),
    Output('hoverdata1', 'children'),
    Output('hoverdata2', 'children'),
    [Input('figure1', 'clickData')])
def display_hover_data(hoverData):
    
    if hoverData is not None:
        traceref = hoverData['points'][0]['curveNumber']
        pointref = hoverData['points'][0]['pointNumber']
        store.append([fig.data[traceref]['name'],
                      fig.data[traceref]['x'][pointref],
                     fig.data[traceref]['y'][pointref]])
        fig.update_layout(title = 'Last label was ' + fig.data[traceref]['name'])
        return fig, json.dumps(hoverData, indent=2), str(store)
    else:
        return fig, 'None selected', 'None selected'

app.run_server(mode='external', port = 7077, dev_tools_ui=True,
          dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
```

CODE # 2 (includes image hover feature):

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

## create sample random data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1,2,3],
    'y': [2,3,4],
    'z': [3,4,5],
    'color': ['red','green','blue'],
    'img_url': [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/2880px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Plotly-logo-01-square.png",
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Pandas_logo.svg/2880px-Pandas_logo.svg.png"
    ]
})

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=df['x'], 
        y=df['y'], 
        z=df['z'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color=df['color'])
    )
])

# turn off native plotly.js hover effects - make sure to use
# hoverinfo="none" rather than "skip" which also halts events.
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo="none", hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(
    scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(range=[-1,8],),
                     yaxis = dict(range=[-1,8],),
                     zaxis = dict(range=[-1,8],),
    ),
)

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="graph-basic-2", figure=fig, clear_on_unhover=True),
    dcc.Tooltip(id="graph-tooltip"),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph-tooltip", "show"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "bbox"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "children"),
    Input("graph-basic-2", "hoverData"),
)
def display_hover(hoverData):
    if hoverData is None:
        return False, no_update, no_update

    # demo only shows the first point, but other points may also be available
    pt = hoverData["points"][0]
    bbox = pt["bbox"]
    num = pt["pointNumber"]

    df_row = df.iloc[num]
    img_src = df_row['img_url']

    children = [
        html.Div([
            html.Img(src=img_src, style={"width": "100%"}),
        ], style={'width': '100px', 'white-space': 'normal'})
    ]

    return True, bbox, children

app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: *The first segment of code below (code # 1) generates a graph for which 1) when you hover over each point, the data associated with each point is displayed and 2) when you click on each point, the data associated with each point is saved to a list* code #1 doesn't do this.  it's all on click.  This really doesn't do much for understanding whether you are trying to do hover or click as the code is all click....  maybe you can disambiguate

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For code #1, when you hover your mouse over each point, you'll see (A) text pop up in a red or purple rectangle which says something like "country=Australia" + other text information. Also for code #1, when you click on each point, it (B) saves data like [['Australia', 1982, 74.74]]. Then for code #2, when you hover over each point, (C) it displays an image.  I would basically like to combine (B) and (C) features into one algorithm. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated the answer,  now does click and hover callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you want a callback that does **hover** and **click**

  - on **hover** display image associated with point and full hover info
  - on **click** update list of clicked points and figure title
- *Assume the dataframe df has a column 'image'* have created one that is a b64 encoded image
- have inserted this into the figure by using **customdata** (**hover_data** parameter in **px**)
- have added an additional **div** *image*
- have changed **callback** to behave as it did before and also contents on new **div**.  This uses b64 encoded image, extending with necessary `"data:image/png;base64,"`
- need to take note of this https://dash.plotly.com/vtk/click-hover and https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks

```
import json
from textwrap import dedent as d
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import dash
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import warnings
import base64, io, requests
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning)

# app info
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
styles = {"pre": {"border": "thin lightgrey solid", "overflowX": "scroll"}}

# data for whare images can be found
df_flag = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """country,Alpha-2 code,Alpha-3 code,URL
Australia,AU,AUS,https://www.worldometers.info//img/flags/small/tn_as-flag.gif
New Zealand,NZ,NZL,https://www.worldometers.info//img/flags/small/tn_nz-flag.gif"""
    )
)

# ensure that images exist on your file system...
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("flags")
if not f.exists():
    f.mkdir()

# download some images and use easy to use filenames...
for r in df_flag.iterrows():
    flag_file = f.joinpath(f'{r[1]["Alpha-3 code"]}.gif')
    if not flag_file.exists():
        r = requests.get(r[1]["URL"], stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
        with open(flag_file, "wb") as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                fd.write(chunk)

# encode
def b64image(country):
    b = io.BytesIO()
    im = Image.open(Path.cwd().joinpath("flags").joinpath(f"{country}.gif"))
    im.save(b, format="PNG")
    b64 = base64.b64encode(b.getvalue())
    return b64.decode("utf-8")


df_flag["image"] = df_flag["Alpha-3 code"].apply(b64image)

# data
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
df = df.merge(df_flag, on="country")  # include URL and b64 encoded image

# plotly figure.  Include URL and image columns in customdata by using hover_data
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="year",
    y="lifeExp",
    color="country",
    title="No label selected",
    hover_data={"URL": True, "image": False},
)
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")

app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.dcc.Graph(
            id="figure1",
            figure=fig,
        ),
        dash.html.Div(
            className="row",
            children=[
                dash.html.Div(id="image"),
                dash.html.Div(
                    [
                        dash.dcc.Markdown(d("""Hoverdata using figure references""")),
                        dash.html.Pre(id="hoverdata2", style=styles["pre"]),
                    ],
                    className="three columns",
                ),
                dash.html.Div(
                    [
                        dash.dcc.Markdown(
                            d(
                                """
              
              Full hoverdata
            """
                            )
                        ),
                        dash.html.Pre(id="hoverdata1", style=styles["pre"]),
                    ],
                    className="three columns",
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ]
)

# container for clicked points in callbacks
store = []


@app.callback(
    Output("figure1", "figure"),
    Output("hoverdata1", "children"),
    Output("hoverdata2", "children"),
    Output("image", "children"),
    [Input("figure1", "clickData"), Input("figure1", "hoverData")],
)
def display_hover_data(clickData, hoverData):
    # is it a click or hover event?
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"] == "figure1.clickData":
        traceref = clickData["points"][0]["curveNumber"]
        pointref = clickData["points"][0]["pointNumber"]
        store.append(
            [
                fig.data[traceref]["name"],
                fig.data[traceref]["x"][pointref],
                fig.data[traceref]["y"][pointref],
            ]
        )
        fig.update_layout(title="Last label was " + fig.data[traceref]["name"])

        return fig, dash.no_update, str(store), dash.no_update
    elif ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"] == "figure1.hoverData":
        # simpler case of just use a URL...
        # dimg = dash.html.Img(src=hoverData["points"][0]["customdata"][0], style={"width": "30%"})
        # question wanted image encoded in dataframe....
        dimg = dash.html.Img(
            src="data:image/png;base64," + hoverData["points"][0]["customdata"][1],
            style={"width": "30%"},
        )

        return fig, json.dumps(hoverData, indent=2), dash.no_update, dimg
    else:
        return fig, "None selected", "None selected", "no image"


# app.run_server(mode='external', port = 7077, dev_tools_ui=True,
#           dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```